# Filterable search not working inside recyclerview inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-filterable

Question -

The main problem is when I run the app I don't see a filterable search working it always shows an invalid search even if I search the exact related text results.
The app doesn't crash as I have already handled the null pointer exception.

> I got a filterable search which is used on appBar. I have used the recycler view inside Fragment - "Home"

**Home Fragment Code**

```
    private RecyclerView recyclerVFragHomeSc;
adapterRecVHomeFrag adapter;
Toolbar toolbar;
private MenuItem menuItem;
private SearchView searchView;
private ArrayList<dataModelRecVFragHome> dataHolder;


    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_toolbar_menu,menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_button);

    searchView = (SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //mysearch(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if(adapter != null){
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "invalid search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

**ADAPTER CLASS**

```
ArrayList<dataModelRecVFragHome> dataHolderBackup;
public adapterRecVHomeFrag(ArrayList<dataModelRecVFragHome> dataHolder) {
    this.dataHolder = dataHolder;
    dataHolderBackup = new ArrayList<>(dataHolder);
}
    @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}

    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence keyword) {

            //tempo array list for filtered data
            ArrayList<dataModelRecVFragHome> filteredData = new ArrayList<>();

            if(keyword.toString().isEmpty())
                filteredData.addAll(dataHolderBackup);

            else {
                for (dataModelRecVFragHome obj : dataHolderBackup) {
                    if (obj.getTitle().toString().toLowerCase().trim().contains(keyword
                            .toString().toLowerCase().trim()) ||
                            obj.getDescription().toString().toLowerCase().trim().contains(keyword
                                    .toString().toLowerCase().trim()))
                        filteredData.add(obj);
                }
            }
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredData;
                return  results;
        }

        //Main thread ui
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            dataHolder.clear();
            dataHolder.addAll((ArrayList<dataModelRecVFragHome>)filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```